# Como é feita uma boa documentação usando SCRUM?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, documentação, metodologia-ágil, scrum

Estou elaborando uma documentação usando o método ágil *SCRUM*, não sei se estou no caminho certo, e muitas pessoas tem dificuldade nisso, por isso resolvi realizar tal pergunta, atualmente coloquei na documentação:

- **Introdução**: resumo do que o sistema será.
- **R. Funcionais (Product Backlog)**: lista de tudo que o sistema deverá fazer.
- **R. Não Funcionais**: o que o sistema deve ter para funcionar. Exemplo: versão do PHP, banco de dados, framework.
- **Primeira Sprint**:

[image: primeira sprint]

Nessa *sprint* coloquei qual requisito ela irá atender, além do planejamento da mesta feita com diagramas de atividades e classes.

Esses foram os tópicos que coloquei até então, fazendo a segunda *sprint* apenas quando terminar a primeira (pois sou só eu no projeto).

A dúvida é, quais pontos uma documentação usando o *SCRUM* deve ter? Os tópicos principais a serem expostos e como expor.

**P.S:** No caso de diagramas, deveria ter diagramas de classe dos testes automatizados?

Comment: Não sou expert do assunto, mas acho que a ideia de utilizar uma metodologia ágil é não perder tempo utilizando UML e criando toda a sua documentação(diagramas). A ideia é basicamente anotar as necessidades do cliente, colocar no backlog, verificar prioridade de implementação, implementar e apresentar o resultado. Repetir este ciclo até o sistema ficar pronto.

Comment: @mauhumor creio que isso seja um critério não obrigatório, em alguns lugares são usados e outros não. Quando vi essa matéria foi isso que deu a entender, levando como opcional decidi acrescentar esses dois. Mas também não é certeza kk por isso da pergunta

Comment: Sim, sim, SCRUM não é uma religião que deve ser seguido ao pé da letra. Você pode adaptar a sua necessidade. Mas fazendo uma documentação muito extensa, você perde a agilidade, que é um dos objetivos das metodologias ágeis. Mas se realmente essa documentação vai ser necessária depois e os requisitos são bem definidos. De modo que no meio do projeto o cliente não vai pedir para modificar tudo. Não vejo problema nenhum em misturar com UML.

Comment: realmente, se for bem exposto o uso de diagramas pode se tornar inútil.

Comment: Pode até ser, ou não. O cliente pede para mudar algo e te da um prazo curto. Você vai atualizar a documentação, ou ir direto pro código, você vai ter tempo para isso? Vai precisar de um tempo de experiência para que você possa perceber o que realmente é realmente útil ou perda de tempo. Principalmente quando você precisar se apoiar na documentação para reparos, ou designar outro programador para trabalhar no sistema.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alô, Ivcs!

Vou tentar responder a pergunta "Como é feita uma boa documentação usando SCRUM?" respondendo algo mais genérico como "Como é uma documentação ágil?", ok? Vou tentar ser bem informal e falar bem simples...

Primeiramente, é um mito dizer que modelos ágeis de desenvolvimento abandonam por completo a documentação. Eles apenas racionalizam a criação de documentos no sentido de fazer as coisas com MOTIVO.

Outro detalhe é a diferença que se faz em modelo ágil é entre documento e modelo (diagramas). Um documento possui vários modelos, mas não se deve criar um modelo necessariamente para documentar, pois você pode criar um modelo apenas para raciocinar ou facilitar a explicação sobre algo bem específico.

Você não cria um diagrama de classes igual ao que você fez só para por no documento, você vai criar quando precisar explicar algo a alguém da equipe ou mesmo só para pensar nos relacionamentos. E mais, essa modelagem nem mesmo precisa ser um processo peso pesado, cheia de uso de ferramentas CASE de última geração, pode ser usada uma ferramenta mais simples (ou mesmo desenho em papel =D).

Perceba que em modelos clássicos tudo gira em torno da documentação (peça chave nesses modelos), até mesmo se cria modelos só pra documentar e se documenta só por mero formalismo. Na metodologia ágil o documento perde importância (mas não é abandonado!!) e você tem um pensamento chamado de "modelagem ágil", onde você não modela para documentar, mas modela porque realmente precisa pra um fim bem específico.

Não se cria documento por criar em um desenvolvimento ágil. Você cria um documento...

- Por que o cliente requisitou
- Para definir um modelo de contrato (nesses casos é necessário um documentação mais detalhada)
- Apoiar a comunicação com um grupo externo
- Raciocinar

Um documento ágil:

- Maximiza o retorno dos clientes
- Magro e econômico
- Tem um propósito específico
- Descreve informações que tem menor probabilidade de mudar
- Contém apenas "coisas boas de se saber"
- Tem cliente específico e facilitam o trabalho desse cliente
- É suficientemente preciso, consistente e detalhado
- Suficientemente indexado

Comment: Ajudou bastante, eram coisas que eu sabia, mas como aprendi método ágil meio envolto com documentação pesada eu acabava ficando em dúvidas, mas sua resposta foi bem clara e tirou as dúvidas, obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Por ser uma metodologia ágil o Scrum parte do pré-suposto que a equipe é pró-eficiente, ou seja, consegue produzir o máximo de valor com o mínimo de artefato quando falando em documentação. Isto gera confiança e consequentemente gera resultado.

Por ser ágil e estar em constante evolução um projeto dentro do Scrum não pode ter documentação extensa e complexa, até mesmo porque isto vai na contramão dos pilares do Scrum: Transparência -> Inspeção -> Adaptação.

A documentação utilizada um projeto Scrum normalmente é composta por:

- User story
- Requisitos
- Diagramas

Em resumo é uma documentação mais enxuta com a linguagem do cliente e mais objetiva possível.

Observação: É importante lembrar que o "Product Owner" estará sempre presente durante o projeto para esclarecer quaisquer dúvidas que a equipe tiver sobre a documentação.